# SSH from Local to A, A to B and run multiple commands on B

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting

Im currently using the line of script below to ssh from my local machine to a server (lets call it ip-address1) then from that machine i want to ssh to another machine (lets call this machine ip-address2). The script i use is as follows:

```
sshpass -p mypassword ssh -tt user@ip-address1 ssh -tt -i /root/.ssh/vm_private_key user@ip-address2 "pwd; ls;"
```

The problem is only the first command (pwd) executes on ip-address2 then it closes and the ls command executes on ip-address1 before it then closes. I want both commands to execute on ip-address2. The output in my terminal is something like the following:

```
/home/user (pwd command executing here)
Connection to ip-address2 closed.
//files then get outputted here (ls command executes after ip-address2 has 
closed)
Connection to ip-address1 closed.
```

I think there may be something wrong with my quotation but i cant figure out what. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any way to test this, but try the following:

```
sshpass -p mypassword ssh -tt user@ip-address1 \
    "ssh -tt -i /root/.ssh/vm_private_key user@ip-address2 'pwd; ls;'"
```

You definitely need to quote the entire command you want to run on the `ip_address1`, including the command you'll pass to `ip_address2`.

**Edit**

I'm in an environment where I have multiple machines to test; the following command works for me:

```
ssh snewell@<host sanitized> \
    "ssh <host2 sanitized> 'hostname; ls -a <path sanitized>;'"
```

`hostname` definitely displays the result of the final server (host2), and `ls` is listing a directory that the first host doesn't have.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for the assistance here, unfortunately that does not seem to have done it. It does seem closer though. Output now is something like: /home/user (pwd command executing here).
//command not found (seems to be looking for something) Connection to ip-address2 has closed
Connection to ip-address1 closed.

Comment: @CiaranWhyte - Just for kicks, can you add a `hostname` to your command (after the `pwd`)?  Let's just verify you're actually on the final host when these commands get executed.

Comment: I can do that but if i put hostname after pwd then it wont execute. The ls command is after pwd and it does not execute. The ip-address2 machine simply runs pwd and closes. I resolved the :command not found output it was due to a dos/unix conflict which generated ^M line endeing.

Comment: So to clarify, right now im running the original code you suggested. I see three lines of output in the following order 1.The result of pwd 2.Closing ip-address2 machine 3. Closing ip-address1 machine ....the ls command is never shown.

Comment: If the directory is empty, `ls` won't print results.  That's why I wanted you to add `hostname`, so it's something else that will print output and makes it obvious whether the series of commands is running on `ip-address2`.

Comment: Good thinking ;) i honestly thought i had checked the directory manually to ensure it has files on it. Turns out id checked the directory of the first machine, not the second which is where i was running the commands. Once i added hostname i got output for both. Thanks Stephan you legend :D